# guide to use the MASL java SDK to authenticate user in azure function developed in java

Tags: java, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-java-sdk

Please help me to find out the documentation on how to use java MASL SDK to get access_token for a service principal.
I am looking to find the documentation or GIT links which can guide me how to use the MASL library including the code samples.

I have gone through this link but it does not help me much : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows

And, I am not expecting code samples to be shared here. I just want to find out where to find such data. I am struggling a lot when it comes to finding the right knowledge with respect to azure learning. What am I missing here? Is there any azure reference link available to find such information at a centralized place?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that, based on your requirement you can make use of `Authorization code Flow` if you want the user to sign-in and authenticate and if you want to access API using Application then make use of `Client Credential Flow`.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added API permission:

[image]

For Client-Credential Flow, refer this [**GitHub**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/tree/dev/msal4j-sdk/src/samples/confidential-client) blog by *siddhijain*.

> Use the MASL java SDK to authenticate user in azure function developed in java.

Assuming that you want to authenticate user, you can make use of **[Authorization code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal)** to generate access token.

I generated the **Authorization code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectUri
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

A sign-in screen will appear for authenticating the user:

[image]

[image]

To generate the access token, I used below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

I am able to call the Function by using above generated access token:

[image]

To implement the above in MSAL Java library, **refer** the below GitHub Blogs:

[Microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/msal-node/auth-code AzureAD by derisen](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/auth-code)

[Microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/samples/msal-node  AzureAD by rgins16](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples#which-sample-should-i-review)